# Question about proof of root test for $\alpha=\lim \sup a_{n}>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

> Given $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ let $\lim sup (a_{n})^{1/n}=\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> a) If $\alpha<1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges.
>
> b) If $\alpha>1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ diverges.

Definition:

$\lim sup=\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_{k \geq n} a_{k}$

I have already been able to proof a) with this definition.

Proof:

Let $\beta-\alpha>0$, then by definition $\exists N$ s.t. $n \geq N \implies \lvert sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}-\alpha \rvert<\beta-\alpha$, so $-(\beta-\alpha)<sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}-\alpha<\beta-\alpha \implies sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}<\beta$.

Now let $n=N$, then $(a_{k})^{1/k} \leq sup_{k \geq N} (a_{k})^{1/k}<\beta$ for all $k \geq N$. But then $a_{k}<\beta^{k}$, and so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges by the comparison with the geometric sequence.

Now I've tried a similar thing for b).

Proof attempt:

Let $\alpha-\beta>0$, then by definition $\exists N$ s.t. $n \geq N \implies \lvert sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}-\alpha \rvert<\alpha-\beta$, so $-(\alpha-\beta)<sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}-\alpha<\alpha-\beta \implies \beta<sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k})^{1/k}$.

The problem is now that I only know that this supremum is larger than $\beta$, but I need to show that the series can be bounded below by the divergent geometric series.

Am I on the right track here? How can I show this given my definition of $\lim sup$?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Alternatively, what is one of the most basic prerequisites on $(a_n)$ for the series to converge?

Comment: The Cauchy criterion, but in b) I'm trying to show divergence, so not sure what you are alluding to.

Comment: Ok, a hint: what is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1$?

Comment: It's a series with constant terms, so the partial sums are $1,2,3,..$ and it diverges

Comment: What can you say about $|a_n|$ of a convergent series? How does it vary with $n$?

Comment: The terms converge to $0$, so the idea is to show that infinitely many terms are larger than $\alpha$ because then terms cannot go to $0$. And I think this is exactly what @An Jin is doing by constructing a subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

I will say you are on the right track (except using $\beta$. You can use $1+\beta$ for $\beta$ small enough where you wrote $\beta$). Next thing you can do is, think about the definition of the supremum, and find a subsequent of $(a_n)_n$ that goes infinity. It is as follows :

If $\alpha>1$, then for any given $0<\epsilon<\alpha-1$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n\geq N$, $\sup_{k\geq n}(a_k)^{1/k}>1+\epsilon$, i.e. $\exists k_n\geq n$ such that $(a_{k_n})^{1/{k_n}}>1+\epsilon$ for each $n\geq N$. Therefore $a_{k_n}>(1+\epsilon)^{k_n}$, and by letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ you get $a_{k_n}\rightarrow \infty$ (because $k_n\rightarrow \infty$ since $k_n\geq n$). Since $(a_{k_n})_{n\geq N}\subset(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge, i.e. diverge.

edit : I will try to write more precisely. Take any $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<\alpha-1$. Then $$\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\in{\mathbb{N}}(\sup_{k\geq n}(a_k)^{1/k}>1+\epsilon).$$ Then $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}(n\geq N\rightarrow\exists k_n\in{\mathbb{N}}(k_n\geq n\land a_{k_n}>(1+\epsilon)^{k_n}))$$ since for $\textbf{each}$ $n\geq N$, $\sup_{k\geq n}(a_k)^{1/k}>1+\epsilon$. Then now we have  $(a_{k_n})_n$ that goes infinity by $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that part involving $k_{n}$, please? I'm not sure if I'm following.

Comment: So, by limit you have $\exists N\forall n>N(...)$ right? (... is for statement after the quantifiers) For each such $n>N$, by superemum $\exists k_n\geq n,(...)$. The reason $k_n$ is indexed with $n$ is, since $k_n$ is taken for each $n>N$.

Comment: Ah, okay. At first I thought you were referring to subsequences. You mean if we fix $n$, we must have some $(a_{k_{n}})^{1/n}>1+\epsilon$ because otherwise $1+\epsilon$ would be a smaller bound than the sup. However, $(a_{k_{n}})^{1/n}$ depends on $n$ since $sup_{k \geq n}$ depends on $n$ and is a decreasing sequence. So $k_{1}$ works for $n=1$, but it might not work for $n>1$, right?

Comment: No, you are not taking $n=1$. First we take $N$, then you take $n\geq N$, then take $k_n\geq n$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did not write it down correctly, of course we start at N because otherwise the inequality for the sup does not hold. I meant the first element for which $sup_{k \geq n}>1+\epsilon$ holds, i.e. $N$.

Comment: Note that for $\textbf{all}$ $n\geq N$ the statement should hold. I will edit the answer to make it easier to be understood.

Comment: Sorry, another question. I think it should be $\lvert sup_{k \geq n} (\lvert a_{k}\rvert)^{1/k}-\alpha \rvert<\epsilon \implies -(\alpha-1)<-\epsilon<sup_{k \geq n} (\lvert a_{k}\rvert)^{1/k}-\alpha<\epsilon$ 
$\implies sup_{k \geq} n (\lvert a_{1/k})^{k}>1$.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy It does not really matters that you choose $\epsilon$ as in my way or as you wrote in the comment. And also, write absolute value does not really matters (i.e. does not affect the logic here) since we just want to find one subsequence that diverges. And lastly, what you said is not a question, rather, it is a statement.